# Rounding error from BigDecimal to byte array in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

How should one properly handle a conversion rounding error with BigDecimal in Java:

`BigDecimal -> byte[] -> BigDecimal`

I have a custom datatype 32 bytes in length (yep, 32 bytes not 32 bits) and I need to decode the fractional part of `BigDecimal` into `byte[]`.

I understand that I will lose some accuracy. Are there any established techniques to implement such a conversion?

NOTE:
It is fixed point datatype of form `MxN`, where `M % 8 == N % 8 == 0`

Comment: You need to tell us more about the `byte[]` representation, or if that's what you want recommendations on then please say so.  Is it fixed-point or floating-point (The latter is more analogous to `BigDecimal`, but requires additional information about where the point is placed.)  Is it binary?  BCD?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fixed-point fractional part can be interpreted as the numerator, *n*, of a fraction *n*/(2<sup>256</sup>).  I suggest, therefore, computing the `BigDecimal` value representing 1/(2<sup>256</sup>) (this is exactly representable as a `BigDecimal`) and storing a reference to it in a `final static` field.

To convert *to* a `byte[]`, then, use the two-arg version of `BigDecimal.divideToIntegralValue()` to divide the fractional part of your starting number by 1/(2<sup>256</sup>), using the `MathContext` argument to specify the rounding mode you want.  Presumably you want either `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` or `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`.  Then get the `BigInteger` unscaled value of the result (which should be numerically equal to the scaled value, since an integral value should have scale 0) via `BigDecimal.unscaledValue()`.  `BigInteger.toByteArray()` will then give you a `byte[]` closely related to what you're after.<sup>*</sup>

To go the other way, you can pretty much reverse the process.  `BigDecimal` has a constructor that accepts a `byte[]` that, again, is very closely related to your representation.  Using that constructor, convert your `byte[]` to a `BigInteger`, and thence to `BigDecimal` via the appropriate constructor.  Multiply by that stored 1/(2<sup>256</sup>) value to get the fractional part you want.

---

<sup>*</sup> The biggest trick here may involve twiddling signs appropriately.  If your `BigDecimal`s may be negative, then you probably want to first obtain their absolute values before converting to `byte[]`.  More importantly, the `byte[]`s produced and consumed by `BigInteger` use a *two's complement* representation (*i.e.* with a sign bit), whereas I suppose you'll want an unsigned, pure binary representation.  That mainly means that you'll need to allow for an extra bit -- and therefore a whole extra byte -- when you convert.  Be also aware of byte order; check the docs of `BigInteger` for the byte order it uses, and adjust as appropriate.

Comment: Everything cool, except pow() in BigDecimal rejects negative exponent)

Comment: @KostyaKrivomaz, nobody said to use `BigDecimal.pow()`.  But you could if you wanted to do by computing 2^256 and dividing 1 by the result.